# Sending Map<String,List<String>> as request parameter through ajax

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

i want to send a Map through ajax request but i am getting 400 bad request.
My data is like.

```
var idss1 = [];
var idss2 = [];
var idss3 = [];
var idss4 = [];
var idss5 = [];


    map[id_1] = idss1;
    map[id_2] = idss2;
    map[id_3] = idss3;
    map[id_4] = idss4;
    map[id_5] = idss5;
```

wehre all the keys (id_*) are string

Ajax call is

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: myurl,
        dataType: "text",
        data : {allIds : map},
        success: function(response) {...}
```

at server side my method signature is

```
public void myMethod(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("allIds") Map<String, List<String>> ids) {
...
}
```

Kindly help me, i shall be thankful.

Comment: Can you construct a JSON list and send ? Should it be `dataType: "text"`?

Comment: i want to send it as a map not a list. How can i use a json list instead of map, can you kindly help?

Comment: So you can send a JSON map, there are lots of tutorials to do so in net !!!

Comment: what exception are u getting?

Comment: @Kshitij 400 bad request

Comment: What if you replace `Map<String, List<String>>` by `Map<?, ?>`? Does the HTTP error still occur?

Comment: @sp00m thanks for your reply, actually i used JSON map as suggested by  "Noob UnChained" and it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

1) You should never have variables names in a program whose only difference is a number.  That is what arrays are for.  The names of the elements in the array are myArr[0], myArr[1], etc.

2) In java, you can do what's called 'serializing' an object.  Serializing converts an object to a string, and a string can be sent in an ajax request, and then the string can be unserialized in your servlet to create an object from the string.

Serialization to String: [How to binary (de)serialize object into/form string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568248/how-to-binary-deserialize-object-into-form-string)